# Selenium ide read file

Tags: selenium-ide

Is it possible to read any file from selenium ide?
I want share my test case, but i won't share my own settings (logins, passwords etc).
It will be a great feature to read this data from config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium IDE plug-in "SelBlocks" for this purpose. Using this, variables can be configured via external XML and/or JSON files. Refer the plug-in's document for more details.

[Download link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/)

[Document link](http://refactoror.wikia.com/wiki/Selblocks_Reference)